# Javascript variable name status converting a boolean to a string

Tags: javascript

I have just come across some behavior I have never seen before. The javascript in my html page is converting a `boolean` to a `string`

I have a html page that looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var status = true;

   console.log(typeof status) //returns string

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Strangely, when I open the console and type `var test = true`; and then on the following like type `typeof test` it returns `"boolean"`.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and why it is not a `boolean` on both occasions?

Comment: status is a reserved word, change you var name

Comment: @Ronnie lol... .

Comment: You are correct, thanks! Clears a lot of confusion up in my head. Just as a matter of interest even though it is a reserved word, why does it convert it to a string

Comment: Interesting that the behavior of status is such that you can only assign a string to it though.

Comment: javascript is weird, dont feel bad

Comment: It’s not a reserved word; it’s a property on the window that’s a string.

Comment: @Ronnie: It's not a reserved word. It's a predefined global variable in browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status

Comment: alright well I was close

Comment: you were close @Ronnie dont mind them :-)

Comment: If you use `let` or `const`, or wrap your entire script in an IIFE – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript – you can avoid this problem.

Comment: Duplicate? [Javascript treats variable named status as string while treating Status as array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43172331/218196)

Comment: It converts to a string because it sets the text in the browser status bar, which obviously must be a string. There is no standard I can find anywhere that makes this behavior required though.

Comment: You can also do `delete window.status` in Chrome and then use the variable as usual, but you really shouldn't be declaring variables in global scope for exactly this reason.